# A Pell like equation

Tags: diophantine-equations, computational-number-theory, elementary-proofs

If one takes in general $(\star)\, \,x^2-dy^2=C$ where $d$, $C$ in $\mathbb{N}$.

Taking $d=w^2p^2+p$ with $w\in \mathbb{Q}\ge 1$ and $p\in \mathbb{Z}$ which is verified (explained later), for the matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}2w^2p+1&2w(w^2p^2+p)\\2w&2w^2p+1\end{pmatrix}$$ if $X_0$ is a solution to $(\star)$ then $AX_0$ is another one.

Now $w$ could be taken in a cool way basicaly say $d=a^2b^2+cb$ with $c\in\mathbb{Z}$, $|c|<|a|$ and $c$ coprime with $b$ and $a$, letting
$w=\frac{a}{c}$ and $p=cb$ the matrix $A$ is in $\mathbb{Q}$ but can have a power $A^n$ with integer entries. So to say that i didn't find any reference for this idea which is surprising. This is related and known of course as a Pell equation when $w\in \mathbb{N}$.

A question is if there is a related topic discussion to this approach since Pell equations  are known, and as a conjecture to give certain family of $A$  with $A^n$ of integer entries. (It appears there are many). Thanks

Edit, i'll illustrate this in an example just for clarity:
$$x^2-2021y^2=d^2$$ one solution is $(d,0)$, i took $2021$ by chance as it is within what i can get, (i don't know if it should work for $2020$) since $2021=\frac{45^2}{4^2}4^2-4$. An easy argument says if the numerator of $w$ here $45$ is $5 \pmod{8}$ Then $A^3\in \mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ so

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}-1011.5&45472.5\\22.5&-1011.5\end{pmatrix}$$ and  $$A^3=\begin{pmatrix}-4.139590049\times 10^9&1.8609747948\times 10^{11}\\9.2081880\times 10^7&-4.139590049\times 10^9\end{pmatrix}.$$

Edit. It seems such $A$ has an all integer power $A^n$ if and only if $c$ is a power of two and mainly  $|c|= 1, 2, 4$,

Comment: I am not sure if there is a question in this post.

Comment: A question is implicitly if there is a related topic discussion to this approach since Pell equations $(\star)$ are known, besides a natural question rises as a conjecture to give certain $A$ with $A^n$ of integer entries for some $n$ etc.

Comment: Why not edit the question to explicitly ask what you want to know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your question is the following: suppose that for a given positive integer $d$ the equation

$$\displaystyle x^2 - dy^2 = c \text{ } (\ast)$$

has a solution in integers $x,y$ for some integer $c$. Then does there exist an infinite family of solutions generated by $A^k (x,y)^T$ for some $A \in \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ having infinite order?

The answer is yes, and was answered completely by Siegel. Indeed,  the equation $(\ast)$ has finitely many solutions modulo the action induced by the unit group of the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$, which always has rank one. See the following paper of Siegel: [The average measure of quadratic forms with given determinant and signature](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969296?seq=1).

Comment: ok but here i gave the $A$ along. It is related to this. I know there are others given in terms of fundamental solutions theory. Thanks.

Comment: @ToniMhax Siegel also gave an explicit $A$ in terms of a fundamental solution of the equation. It's in the paper.

Comment: but one should compute a fundamental non trivial solution i guess. Here $A$ is in $\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ that we elevate to a certain power iteration...

Comment: @ToniMhax determining whether the equation $x^2 - dy^2 = c$ has a solution in the first place is extremely difficult. Indeed, even in the case of $c = -1$ things are very challenging. We don't know how to count the number of $d \leq X$ for which $x^2 - dy^2 = -1$ has an integer solution for example, and it was only 10 years ago that an upper and lower bound of the correct order of magnitude was established by Fouvry and Kluners.

Comment: Yes of course i'll illustrate the simple algo in an exemple just for trial and record.

Answer (score 0):

Thought it possible to simplify in order to be able to write the solutions of the equation. For this we use the decomposition of the number $c$ on the multipliers.

$$Z^2-dR^2=c=ab$$

To record decisions have to know first the solution of the Pell equation $(Z_1;R_1)$. Although to find all the solutions-it is necessary to substitute all the solutions of this Pell equation.

And solving the following equation Pell $(k_0;n_0)$.

$$k^2-dn^2=1$$

Then the formula is as follows.

$$Z_2=k_0Z_1+dn_0R_1$$

$$R_2=n_0Z_1+k_0R_1$$

The problem in finding the first solution for General Pell equation $(Z_1;R_1)$.

The meaning of the solution is that to factor the number. $c=ab$

Then degradable factoring the difference.  $xy=a-b$

If the following expression may be a square.

$$s^2=\frac{1}{d}((\frac{y+x}{2})^2-a)$$

Then the first solution is written simply.

$$Z_1=ds^2+\frac{y^2-x^2}{4}$$

$$R_1=ys$$

Such record these formulas will greatly simplify the calculations. Always better to have a formula. It's not always true that it works... but it works.

You can also create other formulas...

https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1049910___4

https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048219___2

I will give one example-which shows in which direction it is necessary to look for solutions.

Although it should be mentioned, and the equation: $$aX^2-qY^2=f$$

If the root of the whole: $\sqrt{\frac{f}{a-q}}$

Using equation Pell:  $p^2-aqs^2=1$  solutions can be written:

$$Y=(2aps\pm(p^2+aqs^2))\sqrt{\frac{f}{a-q}}$$

$$X=(2qps\pm(p^2+aqs^2))\sqrt{\frac{f}{a-q}}$$

And for that decision have to find double formula.

$$Y_2=Y+2as(qsY-pX)$$

$$X_2=X+2p(qsY-pX)$$

The interesting thing here is that each solution of the Pell equation determines itself the next formula for solutions of the Pell equation. And there are a lot of different special cases for which it is very easy to find solutions.